# how i can send message to my contact whit telethon API python telegram

Tags: python, api, telegram

when i use this command for see contact :

```
result = client.invoke(GetContactsRequest(""))
print(result)
```

i see this result :

```
(contacts.contacts (ID: 0x6f8b8cb2) = (contacts=['(contact (ID: 0xf911c994) = (user_id=334412783, mutual=False))'], users=['(user (ID: 0x2e13f4c3) = (is_self=None, contact=True, mutual_contact=None, deleted=None, bot=None, bot_chat_history=None, bot_nochats=None, verified=None, restricted=None, min=None, bot_inline_geo=None, id=334412783, access_hash=-8113372651091717470, first_name=khood, last_name=None, username=Mosafer575, phone=19132594548, photo=(userProfilePhoto (ID: 0xd559d8c8) = (photo_id=1436291966805583785, photo_small=(fileLocation (ID: 0x53d69076) = (dc_id=1, volume_id=803110857, local_id=86736, secret=1232685751818265379)), photo_big=(fileLocation (ID: 0x53d69076) = (dc_id=1, volume_id=803110857, local_id=86738, secret=3801220285627155105)))), status=(userStatusOffline (ID: 0x8c703f) = (was_online=2017-06-16 13:09:57)), bot_info_version=None, restriction_reason=None, bot_inline_placeholder=None, lang_code=None))']))
```

now how i can send one  message fore this friend with first_name my friend or user_id or phone or other details in my contact???
 i see this [page](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon_examples/interactive_telegram_client.py) but I din't notice.
please use simple code for this

Comment: I had posted the solution in the other question. Does that help or you still have issues? If yes which part is not working ?

Comment: hi apadana please answer me this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871661/how-to-send-message-with-id-telegram-using-telethon-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your contacts you can use the phone number like you would use an username:

```
client.send_message('+xx123456789', 'hello')
```

---

Old answer:

> ```
> users=['(user (ID: 0x2e13f4c3) ...`
> ```

The `users` list has the user you want to talk to. So you get that user:

```
user = result.users[0]
```

And then you can call `.send_message(user, 'your message')`.

Comment: lonami please answer this my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605436/how-i-can-restore-sessions-in-telethon-telegram

Answer (score 0):

> https://stackoverflow.com/content/img/progress-dots.gif Its easy to show all contact and send messages

```
from telethon.tl.types import InputPhoneContact
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ImportContactsRequest
```

After import

```
contacts = client(GetContactsRequest(0))
client.send_message(contact[<You can use indexing>],'<messages>')
```

> You can send message using contact id

Answer (score 0):

**If sending a message all contract number...**

```
all_contacts = await client(GetContactsRequest(hash=0))
for i in range(len(all_contacts.users)):
   if all_contacts.users[i].phone != None:
      await client.send_message(all_contacts.users[i].phone, 'hello')
   else:
      await client.send_message(all_contacts.users[i].username, 'hello')
```