# how i can restore sessions old in telethon telegram and connect this again(without send again code))

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

i use this script for connect and create sessions in telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
from telethon.utils import get_input_peer
api_id = 7****
api_hash = 'ef584d*****************'
client = TelegramClient('+15159947451', api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request('+15159947451')
client.sign_in('+15159947451', cod)
```

with this cod i can login good in this number telegram and create file:+15159947451.session.

now i close and disconnect, how i can again login this number with this file +15159947451.session.

i use this code but this code have error:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
from telethon.utils import get_input_peer
api_id = 7****
api_hash = 'ef584d180eee*******************'
number='+15152934803'
client = TelegramClient('00', api_id, api_hash)
client.session.try_load_or_create_new(session_user_id='+15159947451')
client.connect()
```

but i have this error

```
raise error
telethon.errors.RPCError: (RPCError(...), 'AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED (401):       The key is not registered in the system.')
```

Comment: how do you disconnet? Are you calling any disconnet function from Telethon at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
client = TelegramClient('+15xxxxxxxxx', api_id, api_hash)
```

You don't have to pass your phone number as a first parameter. You have to pass the name of the session, for instance, 'myname'.

You get this:

```
telethon.errors.RPCError: (RPCError(...), 'AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED (401):       The key is not registered in the system.')
```

Because you've changed the name of the session (and now called it '00'), and you haven't logged it on that one. So in order to solve your problem simply:

```
client = TelegramClient('some_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request('+15xxxxxxxxx')
    client.sign_in('+15xxxxxxxxx', cod)
```

And then remove the `.send_code_request(...)` line:

```
client = TelegramClient('some_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
```

Notice that if you change 'some_name' for some `.session` that doesn't exist yet, you will have to create it again. Also, you can rename the `.session` file to any name you want, and use its name as a parameter (since it already exists).

Comment: @netdevil This is the correct answer, Thanks to Lonami for the answer. I will be removing mine shortly. Go Telethon!

Comment: @Lonami Great work on Telethon. But i am having issues when implementing the login/authorization in Flask.

Answer (score 3):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

# These example values won't work. You must get your own api_id and
# api_hash from https://my.telegram.org, under API Development.
api_id = ****** # Your api_id
api_hash = '********************************' # Your api_hash
phone_number = '+989122594574' # Your phone number

client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()

if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter the code: '))


client.send_message('amir2b', 'Hello! Amir Bashiri')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code only answers are not considered as good answers, please post text explaining what was the issue and how your code resolves it.