# How to send message with @ID telegram using telethon library

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want send message with telethon but i dont have phone number this .
i have only @username Telegram.
with this code i can send message for my contact phone :

```
result = client.invoke(ImportContactsRequest([contact], replace=True))
contacts = client.invoke(GetContactsRequest(""))
for u in result.users:
    client.send_message(u, 'Hi')
```

But i want send message to @username Telegram

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send a message to someone with my telegram bot using their Username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664810/how-can-i-send-a-message-to-someone-with-my-telegram-bot-using-their-username)

Comment: is no duplicate becuase i want use the telethon python api

Comment: You might want to ask on the github page, as I looked through their docs and nothing stood out to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do the following now:

```
client.send_message('username', 'hello')
```

---

Old answer:

It's on the [Project's wiki](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/wiki/Retrieving-an-entity), quoted below.

### Via ResolveUsernameRequest

An "entity" is used to refer to either an [`User`](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/types/user.html) or a [`Chat`](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/types/chat.html) (which includes a [`Channel`](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/constructors/channel.html)). Perhaps the most straightforward way to get these is by [resolving their username](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/contacts/resolve_username.html):

```
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest

result = client.invoke(ResolveUsernameRequest('username'))
found_chats = result.chats
found_users = result.users
# result.peer may be a PeerUser, PeerChat or PeerChannel
```

See [`Peer`](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/types/peer.html) for more information about this result.